# Open my app automatically when in Range of certain location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using an `intent` to switch to `Google Maps` to get the route to a marker that's shown on a map that's implemented in my app. My question is if there is any way to let my app in background to send the location at certain intervals of time, so when the user gets close to the location, when the app is reopened to have the location updated directly, so I would be able to implement the next step of the app.( the app should do something when he is close)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [create and monitor geofence](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#java) for detect user gets close to the location:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (geofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return geofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
        // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return geofencePendingIntent;
    }
```

and then, when user gets close to the location start tracking it directly from your app. Something like that:

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // ...
    protected void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes.getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
            // multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Start tracking user position directly here
            ...

        } else if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            // Stop tracking user position directly here
            ...
        else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                    geofenceTransition));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually managed to solve the issue with the distance. I used a `callback` in `onResume` and do the math on server side. Now I am looking about how to update the location from background, when `Google Maps` navigation is on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work or not but you can try this one. my guess should work.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
```

Comment: Can you please give me a little bit more information about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you cannot keep to get the user location in the background when the system is greater than or equal to android O

[Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

> Solution : You can register a Service in the foreground.
>   Step 1:Create your own service 
>   Step 2:register with Androidmanifest
>   Step 3:Create BroadcastReceiver receiver data 
>   Step 4:In onResume bind and onstop unbind service

[foreground example from google](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main)